# How to register a class in iOS native code in my Flutter app?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app and I'm trying to add native swift code in my Flutter app that contains an SDK's callbacks,

```
class RewardDelegate: NSObject, TapResearchSurveyDelegate, TapResearchRewardDelegate {
    let channel: FlutterMethodChannel
    init(channel: FlutterMethodChannel) {
       self.channel = channel
    }
        func tapResearchSurveyWallOpened(with placement: TRPlacement) {
               channel.invokeMethod("tapResearchSurveyWallOpened", arguments: placement)
           }

           func tapResearchSurveyWallDismissed(with placement: TRPlacement) {
               channel.invokeMethod("tapResearchSurveyWallDismissed", arguments: placement)
           }

            func tapResearchDidReceive(_ reward: TRReward) {
               channel.invokeMethod("tapResearchDidReceive", arguments: reward.rewardAmount)
           }
}
```

I'm confused as to how do I register the class `RewardDelegate` in my `AppDelegate` so I can call the swift callbacks in the dart side of code?

```
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    let rootViewController : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
       let methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "swift_code", binaryMessenger: rootViewController as! FlutterBinaryMessenger)
    let rewardCallback = RewardDelegate(channel: methodChannel)
           methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler {(call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) -> Void in
            switch(call.method) {
            case "init":
            print("app init");
default:
            result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
}
 GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: The [guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab#step-4-add-an-ios-platform-specific-implementation) on flutter.dev might help

Comment: The guide is for extremely basic code and isn't very helpful @dev-aentgs

Comment: Understood. Didn't find much that would help, just this [article](https://60devs.com/how-to-add-native-code-to-flutter-app-using-platform-views-ios.html)